# Value change of autocomplete not reflected in the event function using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working in autocomplete search using anuglar material. Whenever the value of input changes the onProductChange($event, i) function must be triggered. But there is no event triggering.

Html code is

```
<input
                    formControlName="productname"
                    [id]="'productname_' + i"
                    [name]="'productname_' + i"
                    matInput
                    #input
                    type="text"
                    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                    class="form-control"
                    (click)="clicked(input)"
                    (input)="performFiltering(input)"
                    (opened)="performFiltering(input)"
                  />
                  <mat-autocomplete
                    #auto="matAutocomplete"
                    (change)="onProductChange($event, i)"
                  >
                    <mat-option
                      *ngFor="let product of filteroptions | async"
                      [value]="product"
                    >
                      {{product}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-autocomplete>
```

My ts code is

```
filteroptions!: Observable<string[]>;

  resetFilters() {
    this.filteroptions = of(this.productlistss);
  }
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const searchvalue = value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.productlistss.filter((option) =>
      option.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchvalue)
    );
  }
    onProductChange(event: any, index: number) {
        const selectedValue = event?.option?.value;
        console.log(selectedValue);
    }
performFiltering(input: any) {
    if (input.value) {
      this.filteroptions = of(this._filter(input.value));
    } else {
      this.filteroptions = of(this.productlistss);
    }
  }

  clicked(input: any) {
    this.filteroptions = of(this.productlistss);
    if (input.value) {
      this.performFiltering(input);
    }
  }
```

Can someone help in this case.

Comment: I don't see a `change` event in documentation for `matAutoComplete` (https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) . Second of all, why don't you subscribe on formControl change like `this.form.get('productname').valueChanges.subscribe()` and get last emitted value for you control.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my previous answer change it to

Before:

```
(change)="onProductChange($event,i);
```

After:

```
(optionSelected)="onProductChange($event,i);
```

Also this change is needed

```
<input
                formControlName="productname"
                [id]="'productname_' + i"
                [name]="'productname_' + i"
                matInput
                #input
                type="text"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                class="form-control"
                (change)="onProductChange($event,i);
                (click)="clicked(input)"
                (input)="performFiltering(input)"
                (opened)="performFiltering(input)"
              />
```

the ts code will be

```
onProductChange(event: any, index: number) {
    const selectedValue = event?.target?.value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Here I dont need to select from option by clicking. Instead when i type the options, the matched content will be triggered.

Comment: This event should acts like valuechange.subscribe

Comment: @Reegan Please add a change event to the input, updated my answer!

Comment: No I cant get desired output